# java.util.stream.Collectors: Why is the summingInt implemented with an array?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

The standard Collector `summingInt` internally creates an array of length one:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Integer>
summingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper) {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
            () -> new int[1],
            (a, t) -> { a[0] += mapper.applyAsInt(t); },
            (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; return a; },
            a -> a[0], CH_NOID);
}
```

I was wondering if it isn't possible to just define:

```
private <T> Collector<T, Integer, Integer> summingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper) {
    return Collector.of(
            () -> 0,
            (a, t) -> a += mapper.applyAsInt(t),
            (a, b) -> a += b,
            a -> a
    );
}
```

This however doesn't work since the accumulator just seems to be ignored. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `Integer` is immutable, while an `Integer[]` array is mutable. An accumulator is supposed to be stateful.

---

Imagine you've got 2 references to 2 `Integer` objects.

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 2;
```

By nature, the instances you are referring to are immutable: you can't modify them once they have been created.

```
Integer a = 1;  // {Integer@479}
Integer b = 2;  // {Integer@480}
```

You've decided to use `a` as an accumulator.

```
a += b;
```

The value `a` is currently holding satisfies you. It's `3`. However, `a` no longer refers to that `{Integer@479}` you used to have at the beginning.

I added debug statements to your `Collector` and make things clear.

```
public static  <T> Collector<T, Integer, Integer> summingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper) {
  return Collector.of(
      () -> {
        Integer zero = 0;
        System.out.printf("init [%d (%d)]\n", zero, System.identityHashCode(zero));
        return zero;
      },
      (a, t) -> {
        System.out.printf("-> accumulate [%d (%d)]\n", a, System.identityHashCode(a));
        a += mapper.applyAsInt(t);
        System.out.printf("<- accumulate [%d (%d)]\n", a, System.identityHashCode(a));
      },
      (a, b) -> a += b,
      a -> a
  );
}
```

If you use it, you'll notice a pattern like

```
init [0 (6566818)]
-> accumulate [0 (6566818)]
<- accumulate [1 (1029991479)]
-> accumulate [0 (6566818)]
<- accumulate [2 (1104106489)]
-> accumulate [0 (6566818)]
<- accumulate [3 (94438417)]
```

where `0 (6566818)` is not being changed despite all abortive attempts with `+=`.

If you rewrote it to using an `AtomicInteger`

```
public static  <T> Collector<T, AtomicInteger, AtomicInteger> summingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper) {
  return Collector.of(
      () -> {
        AtomicInteger zero = new AtomicInteger();
        System.out.printf("init [%d (%d)]\n", zero.get(), System.identityHashCode(zero));
        return zero;
      },
      (a, t) -> {
        System.out.printf("-> accumulate [%d (%d)]\n", a.get(), System.identityHashCode(a));
        a.addAndGet(mapper.applyAsInt(t));
        System.out.printf("<- accumulate [%d (%d)]\n", a.get(), System.identityHashCode(a));
      },
      (a, b) -> { a.addAndGet(b.get()); return a;}
  );
}
```

you would be seeing a true accumulator (as a part of [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)) in action

```
init [0 (1494279232)]
-> accumulate [0 (1494279232)]
<- accumulate [1 (1494279232)]
-> accumulate [1 (1494279232)]
<- accumulate [3 (1494279232)]
-> accumulate [3 (1494279232)]
<- accumulate [6 (1494279232)]
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit, where this is readable in terms of code, or at least give a hint?

Comment: Why are you talking about `Integer[]`, while the code in the question is using `int[]`?

Comment: Immutable or not, the point is, `(a, b) -> a += b` changes the parameter, which has no effect as Java is call-by-value. In case of the accumulator, which is a `BiConsumer`, a function like `(a, b) -> a += b` has no persistent effect, whereas in case of the combiner, which is a `BinaryOperator`, the result of the expression is used, so `(a, b) -> a += b` will have the same affect as `(a, b) -> a + b`. In either case, changing the parameter is pointless.